# Dynamic Filters for Graphql Queries with TypeOrm

Tags: typescript, express, graphql, apollo, typeorm

I am creating a graphQL query using Apollo, typescript and TypeOrm.  Currently I have just one table called users.  I then have a getUsers graphql query. Using typeOrm I return users in my resolver using the find() method.  My question is there a way in typeOrm or Apollo to have optional filters on users so I can pass in an optional id or pass in nothing to return all users in the same query.  What options are available to accept essentially optional filters without having to make a multiple queries.  Thanks.

Query I want to use

```
query noFilters {
  getUsers {
    id
    firstName
  }
}
## return all users

query withFilters {
  getUsers (filters: {id: [1]}) {
    id
    firstName
  }
}
## return just user with ID of 1
```

User entity

```
import {Entity, PrimaryGeneratedColumn, Column, BaseEntity} from "typeorm";

@Entity()
export class User extends BaseEntity{

    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn({name: "user_id"})
    id: number;

    @Column({name: "first_name" })
    firstName: string;
}
```

Resolver

```
export const resolvers = {
  Query: {
    getUsers: async (_: any, args: any) => {
      const { id } = args;

      return await User.find({where: {}});
    }
  }
};
```

Types

```
export const typeDefs = gql`
  type Query {
    getUsers(id: [Int!]): [User]
  }

  type User {
    id: Int!
    firstName: String!
  }
`;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
export const resolvers = {
  Query: {
    getUsers: async (_: any, args: any) => {
      const { id, where } = args;

       if (args.where){
           where = args.where;
       }

      return await User.find({where: where});
    }
  }
};
```